# implicit apply method in scala class

Tags: scala, apply, implicit

I am learning scala implicits.
In below sample code, implicit apply is not getting invoked automatically :

```
package learn

object ImplicitApplyInClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {


    implicit val ss = "abc"

    //This is working
    val a = A(1).apply.toUpperCase

    //This is giving compile time error
    //val b = A(1).toUpperCase
  }
}

case class A(id: Int) {
  implicit def apply(implicit s: String) = {
    s.toUpperCase    
  }
}
```

Kindly suggest why apply is not getting invoked implicitly, when the implicit parameter is available in thr scope?

Answer (score 2):

You can add empty parameter list and this will work:

```
  case class A(id: Int) {
    implicit def apply()(implicit s: String) = {
      s.toUpperCase
    }
  }

  val b = A(1)().toUpperCase
  println(b) // ABC
```

Here `apply` works not as an implicit conversion.

> An implicit conversion from type `S` to type `T` is defined by an implicit
>   value which has function type `S => T`, or by an implicit method
>   convertible to a value of that type.
>
> Implicit conversions are applied in two situations:
>
> •  If an expression `e` is of type `S`, and `S` does not conform to the expression’s expected type `T`.
>
> •  In a selection `e.m` with `e` of type `S`, if the selector `m` does not denote a member of `S`.
>
> In the first case, a conversion `c` is searched for which is applicable
>   to `e` and whose result type conforms to `T`. In the second case, a
>   conversion `c` is searched for which is applicable to `e` and whose result
>   contains a member named `m`.

From [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-conversions.html).

In your code it's none of the cases.

Case 1 is not applicable since `apply` is `String => String`. Case 2 is not applicable since there is no implicit conversion `A => { def toUpperCase }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
object ImplicitApplyInClass {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    implicit val ss = "abc"
    val b = A(1).toUpperCase
    println(b)
  }
}
object A {
  implicit def f(a: A)(implicit s: String): String = s
}
case class A(id: Int)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define an implicit method inside `class A` this isn't at all the same as defining an implicit conversion from this class.

It's usable as an implicit in the scope where it's defined, but it's an implicit conversion from `String` to `String`, which the compiler won't have any reason to use implicitly.